# Community Promotion Ads - 2017

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It is a bit late into this new year, being that we're already in the second month, but we are now cycling the Community Promotion Ads for 2017!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- interesting unix and linux related open source apps
- the site's twitter account
- script packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/4337).

Comment: Noob question: is it allowed to suggest a community ad related to a project I developed?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto if it's relevant to the site there should be nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto sure, if people don't like it, it won't be upvoted. It's quite common actually. For example, mattdm is the Fedora project leader and has posted a few Fedora-related ads, and Ole Tange is the maintainer of GNU parallel and has posted an add about that excellent tool. Since both Fedora and GNU Parallel are very much on topic here, those adds are welcome and tend to be upvoted every year.

Comment: Thank you guys, I've posted one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Community Promotion Ads - 2018](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4765/community-promotion-ads-2018)

Answer (score 24):

[image: Vi and Vim Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 20):

[image: GNU Parallel - for people who live life in the parallel lane]

Answer (score 18):

[image: Unix-like operating system that is free software]

Answer (score 17):

[image: Why zsh is cooler than your shell]

Comment: wanna post this on [ubuntu.se] too? I like it. https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16682/community-promotion-ads-2017

Comment: @Seth Done. You could just have copied it.

Comment: Since it was your work I figured I'd give you a chance. Otherwise I would have :)

Comment: @Seth It isn't my work at all! The image is by Brendon Rapp, it's from the slide deck I link to. I've just posted an image I made — you can see the difference between someone with visual skills and me.

Answer (score 11):

[image: Fedora distro news for users]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Fedora Server: The latest technology and a stable foundation for your apps and services.]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Greg's (GreyCat's) Bash Wiki]

Answer (score 8):

[image: The Linux workstation you've been waiting for]

Answer (score 8):

[image: The universal operating system]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Create and run applications in Linux containers.]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Internet of Things Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Check out the Area 51 DevOps Proposal!]

Comment: go, go, go ....

Answer (score 4):

[image: RecuperaBit – Open Source NTFS Recovery]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Algernon Web Server]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Sawfish — the extensible window manager]

Comment: Yeah, so I suck at composing screenshots. Better ad welcome.

Comment: +1 just for the xeyes

Comment: Sorry, I had to downvote for the old-GNOME style theme... it makes eyes hurt. :(

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto But as you can see from the foreground window, I'm in the process of changing themes! (Is that the old-Gnome theme? I had no idea. Why does it make eyes hurt???)

Comment: Well, it was a bit tongue-in-cheek but I guess probably I am just picky about themes. Now for a more serious feedback, IMHO your banner is way too crowded. My 2 cents suggestion would be to post another version with less elements and less text. :)

Answer (score 3):

[image: Arch wiki]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Fedora Loves Python. Learn why...]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Linux Mint Debian Edition (LMDE) is a semi-rolling distribution based on Debian Testing.]

Answer (score 0):

[image: You can also join us in the CS room, http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59701/join-cs-educators]

Answer (score 0):

[image: See all questions with active bounties]

Answer (score -3):

[image: Follow us on Twitter]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Answer (score -5):

[image: Free Software Foundation Europe]

Comment: An ad that doesn't give any hint of what it's about is just clickbait.

Comment: I haven't thought it like that, sorry. Cool, I'll edit it then.